# JSON Error when loading website

Tags: virtocommerce

I get this error when I try to load the website. I am using the latest version.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'VirtoCommerce.ApiClient.DataContracts.Stores.Store[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'message', line 2, position 13.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'VirtoCommerce.ApiClient.DataContracts.Stores.Store[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'message', line 2, position 13.

Source Error: 


Line 174:                //return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
Line 175:
Line 176:                var taskObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
Line 177:
Line 178:                // the following will reduce number of serializations

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Virto\STOREFRONT\ApiClient\BaseClient.cs    Line: 176
```

Answer (score 0):

we just updated the source code, please try again. There was an error in CMS module initialization that expected directory to exist.

You can see more detailed exception by navigating to /admin url.

Comment: if it is deployed in azure, can you send me a (support@virtocommerce.com) an address and login/password for admin site?

Comment: also do you have any stores defined under stores in admin?

Comment: It's running locally. All I did is downloaded the source, set up the two solutions like stated in the getting started doc. I am using IIS instead of IIS Express. Went to the admin url then to the website url.

Comment: Try opening the following url: http://localhost/admin/api/mp/stores and see what output you get. We also just did a big update to a source code that you might want to checkout.

Comment: This is what I get from that link. Is there supposed to be a mpcontroller class?
{
  "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://virto/admin/api/mp/stores'.",
  "messageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'mp'."
}

Comment: Yes, that is a MerchandiseModule that contains StoresController. You can see how it is supposed to look at: http://virtoadmin.azurewebsites.net/admin/api/mp/stores.

Comment: I am going to wait till this software is officially released. I have spent too much time on it just to get it running.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, we appriciate it. I'll let you know when we have the next stable release. We can also get on the phone/joinme to make sure everything is configured correctly.

Comment: I experiencing the same problem here, locally, downloaded the repository a few minutes ago..
>>No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Store[]' from content with media type 'text/html'.

Comment: can you try opening the url of admin with the following: "http://localhost/admin/api/mp/stores"

Comment: yes i also get> No type was found that matches the controller named 'mp'.
in the webadmin there are no modules installed.. how can we do this? is there a relation to this maybe?

Comment: Did you complete steps under "Configure IIS" in http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Source+Code+Getting+Started? It looks like you don't have modules folder setup correctly.

Comment: I gave, but continued to get 500.19 error. so i changed now the user to a local admin instead of iis user.. for testing purposes its ok..

Comment: I have the same error in version 2.4 (download source today)

Comment: Kaseem, when you open admin and go to to "configuration/modules" blade, do you see any modules in the list? If not, make sure you don't have source code extracted to personal documents folder (we saw some customers having issues with modules not being copied) and instead extract it to somewhere like: "c:\projects\vc-community" folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same issue, I can see modules in the admin, but store front throws the above exception.

Comment: can you send us email with screenshot of modules blade, iis configuration and frontend error to support@virtocommerce.com?